# Outlook Add-in command button disabled when composing

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

My add-in has a `MessageComposeCommandSurface` `ExtensionPoint` that adds a button to the ribbon when the user is composing a message. I expected the button to always be enabled when it is visible (e.g. when the user is composing a new message or replying to an existing one), but sometimes it is greyed out/disabled and I'm not sure why.

Does anyone know the exact circumstances for when an add-in ribbon button is greyed out/disabled?

Comment: They can be grayed out if the message is DRM enable, SMIME signed or encrypted. (note that support for SMIME signed messages in Outlook 2016 C2R versions, is expected in a future version). If this is not your case, sending a screenshot of the window, and your manifest may help us debug.

Comment: Thanks! I'm still gathering information from the users who are experiencing this, but is it possible that having a different add-in installed could affect whether my add-in is disabled?

Or is it only the above things that you mentioned that can affect it?

Comment: Installing another web addin, should not be able to disable another one. However, some COM add-ins that use custom forms are incompatible with Web Add-ins. If you click the add-in button in the Explorer (reading pane) view, it should tell you so.

Comment: Some of the other scenarios that could disable add-ins are: If the item is in Outbox, Drafts, or Sync Issues. (+ Junk Mail for compose), Or if the item is embedded. (a .msg file or an attachment on another message).

Comment: Thanks! Seems like it is a COM add-in (https://en.todoist.com/outlook) that is causing our web add-in to be disabled when composing an email.

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable some COM add-in and then enable it again. In my case it helped to make buttons active.